# Best way to measure time to expiration for options?

Tags: options, implied-volatility, time, expiration

From my reading it seems that only trading days should be accounted for when calculating time to expiration. On the other hand, I see that VIX is calculated using every day until expiration without exception. Which way is best in the context of calculating the implied volatility of SPY options?

Comment: Usually as accurate as possible and every day. Bloomberg for example uses minutes to expiry for equity derivatives and act/365 daycount. What really matters is being consistent with pricers and ivol computation. Some markets like Brazil use 252d by convention.